# Does this define a norm s.t. set of matrices is Banach algebra?

Tags: banach-algebras

As I asked in [this comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046017/algebra-of-matrices-equivalence-of-norms#comment2130928_1046081):

If $a$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and we define

$$  \|a\|_p = \left ( \max_j \sum_i |a_{ij}|^p \right)^{1 \over p}$$

or

$$ \|a\|_p = \left ( \max_i \sum_j |a_{ij}|^p \right)^{1 \over p}$$

Does this norm make the set of matrices a Banach algebra?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true at least if $p >\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$. Take the following $2\times 2$ matrices:

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right), B =  \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right). $$

Then for your first $p$-norm, $||A|| = ||B|| = 2^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and

$$||AB|| = \left|   \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)\right| = (2^p +1)^{\frac{1}{p}} > ||A|| \cdot ||B||. $$

I guess these norms do not define a Banach algebra for all $p \geq 1$. But I cannot find a counterexample yet.